# Is it possible to turn my surface pro into a midi input device for my mac book pro

Tags: software

I have surface pro and I use GarageBand on osx. I was wondering if there is anything I could do to input MIDI from the device (maybe some sort of software that would turn my touch screen surface pro into a midi device)

I've tried searching google but perhaps I am using wrong keywords.

Comment: idk specifically for a Surface, I'm on iOS.. but Google Midi OSC - the protocol exists, you just need to find appropriate software for your platform. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_Control

Comment: Possibly. But wouldn't a cheap MIDI keyboard be much easier?

Answer (score 2):

An example of a software you could use as a midi interface would be xotopad

If you wanna try Ableton live, you could even use something cool like yeco.io (not free)

As you want to send the MIDI information to your macbook, you could use something like midinet, which can be found here: https://www.humatic.de/htools/mnet/man.htm

It is an Windows and OSX MIDI driver that can transfer and receive MIDI information using various network protocols (Multicast, RTP, Bluetooth, ADB, WebSockets and Serial). It can even communicate with other clients on android, linux, windows and OSX

However, I would really recommend using a real hardware MIDI controller as it is significantly easier to set up and use, and much more efficient.
My personal recommandations would be something like a Nektar Impact LX49+, an Akai Professional MPK249 or an Arturia MiniLab MkII 25 if you are on a really tight budget.

These are all USB, and easy to setup in GarageBand.

Comment: Welcome to Music Stack Exchange.  Your answer is well worded and clearly answers the question.  Thanks for contributing.

Answer (score 1):

You could give [MIDI Control](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/midi-control/9wzdncrdnkck) a go (you also need to install the [server](http://www.midicontrol.net/server/) on your computer). It's an editable control surface that works over Wifi (as far as I can tell, I haven't tried it).

It's inspired by [TouchOSC](http://hexler.net/software/touchosc), for iOS and Android.